# Detect Firefox support for screen sharing

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia, screensharing

Firefox, since version 52, will support screen sharing via:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { mediaSource: 'screen' }}) 
  .then(stream => { ... });
```

Check out [this test page to see it in action](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html).

I would like to know whether there is a way to detect whether a browser supports `{ mediaSource: 'screen' }`?

I would like to only give the option to share the screen with users that have the ability to share. So I'd like to be able to feature detect this.

Comment: screensharing has been implemented for ages. FF52 just removed the need for a whitelist entry or an extension that modifies the whitelist.

Comment: Yes, good point. Are you saying that Firefox before 52 would indeed claim to support `mediaSource` and make the check from jib not useful? (Unless you are on the old whitelist...)

Comment: Yes. Just check for Firefox version >= 52 (or rely on extension). Fortunately the last ESR is 52 even though there are reports of people still using FF45...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated answer:** [`getDisplayMedia`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#mediadevices-additions) is now the correct API for screen-sharing, with support in all major browsers for a couple of years now (in Firefox since 66+). So the correct API is:

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
```

And the correct way to **feature detect** it is:

```js
console.log(navigator.mediaDevices &&
            "getDisplayMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices);
```

This is `false` on mobile where support is lacking (Firefox for Android & Chrome for Android).

It's also `false` over insecure `http` (non-https) connections where `navigator.mediaDevices` itself is `undefined`, an object considered a "powerful feature".

**Answer for really old Firefox < [66](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321221):**

⚠️ *Do not rely on this answer in newer browsers, as this constraint is going away!*

> a way to detect whether a browser supports { mediaSource: 'screen' }?

The pedantic answer is the following will tell you if the `mediaSource` constraint is supported:

```js
console.log(!!navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints().mediaSource);
```

Unfortunately, [`mediaSource`](https://fluffy.github.io/w3c-screen-share/#screen-based-video-constraints) is non-standard, and only implemented in Firefox. <strike>Firefox is as of this writing the only browser to enable screen-sharing without a plugin.</strike>

Chrome has a different non-standard API using `chromeMediaSource` available as a plug-in, using an older constraints syntax, but it (rightly) does not appear in the new `getSupportedConstraints`.

<strike>It's a bit of a mess still.</strike> Long-term browsers may end up implementing [`getDisplayMedia`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#dfn-getdisplaymedia) instead.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was looking through `getSupportedConstraints` and got hung up on `browserWindow` for some reason and completely missed `mediaSource`. I realise this is all non-standard, and hopefully there is a decent standard in the future (`getDisplayMedia` seems like a good idea). Thank you!

Comment: Chrome 70 now supports `getDisplayMedia()` [under a flag](https://addpipe.com/blog/screen-capture-in-chrome-70-with-getdisplaymedia/)