# Screensharing in Angular 6 in Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, webrtc, screensharing, get-display-media

I'm making an Angular application and I need to be able to share the users screen. 
I'm using adapter.js version 6.4.8 and testing it in Firefox Developer 64.0b11 & Firefox 63.0.3, I know there are a lot of differences in implementations between browsers. I want to make the application work in Firefox at least, if I can support more browsers that's even better.

After running the following command

```
npm install webrtc-adapter && @types/webrtc
```

I imported the adapter like this:
[import 'webrtc-adapter'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBeHB.png)

There are a lot of changes being made around capturing screens in webRTC recently it seems, the most recent draft of WebRTC specs says you have to implement screencapture like this:

```
try {
  let mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true});
  videoElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Unable to acquire screen capture: ' + e);
}
```

[Implementation in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25m4l.png)

Using this method gives the error in both versions of Firefox:

```
TypeError: "navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is not a function"
```

Also, in the node CLI if gives me this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/video/video.component.ts(32,52): error TS2339: Property 'getDisplayMedia' does not exist on type 'MediaDevices'.
```

I also found this post: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/20EhEy_ahKg
Which states (I think?) that the navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is not supported until Firefox 64/65.

But isn't that what the adapter.js API is for? I thought adapter.js acted as an abstraction layer between the spec and different browser implementations.

At this point I don't know what I'm doing wrong, am I importing the webrtc-adapter wrong in my Angular project, interpreting the specs wrong?

I hope I provided you with enough information for you to help me, I'd really appreciate help with this problem because webRTC is new to me and I don't know what to do next.

Handy links I found trying to solve this problem:

[Share screen in Firefox using RTCMultiConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350985/share-screen-in-firefox-using-rtcmulticonnection/53352888#53352888)

https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/getdisplaymedia-now-available-in-adapter-js/

https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/q75yb8pf

These are solutions of how to solve this problem in javascript, but I can't seem to make it work in typescript.

EDIT: I got it to work thanks to the answers of Philipp Hancke & jib, what I did is import the webrtc-adapter like this:

```
import adapter from "webrtc-adapter";
```

And called it from my code like this:

```
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (adapter.browserDetails.browser == 'firefox') {
      adapter.browserShim.shimGetDisplayMedia(window, 'screen');
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true}).then(this.onSucces).catch(this.onError);
  }

  onSucces(stream: MediaStream): void{
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = stream;   
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    };
  }

  onError(error: Error):void {
    console.log('Error message: ' + error.message);
    console.log('Error name: ' + error.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screensharing is not shimmed by default, see [the mozilla hacks post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/getdisplaymedia-now-available-in-adapter-js/) for instructions how to use getDisplayMedia. Also make sure you are using the latest adapter.js version, getDisplayMedia moved recently.

Comment: When trying to use adapter.browserDetails.browser & adapter.browserShim.shimGetDisplayMedia() typescript gives the following error:   [ts] Cannot find name 'adapter'. [2304], do you know why this is? It seems like it doesn't know what adapter is and can't access. Is it a problem with the importing of webrtc-adapter? I'm using version 6.4.8 of webrtc-adapter which is the latest.

Comment: try importing like this: import adapter from "webrtc-adapter";
beyond that it might be a typescript thing which i know nothing about.

Comment: Yeah that did the job, thanks a lot! And keep up the good work ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Firefox with [adapter-latest.js](https://webrtchacks.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js) like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/q75yb8pf/):

```
adapter.browserShim.shimGetDisplayMedia(window, "window"); // or "screen"

(async () => {
  try {
    video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Unfortunately, Firefox still forces the app to pick between sharing the full screen or a window. This should be fixed once it's supported natively.