# Check if browser/platform support screen capturing via `getDisplayMedia`

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediadevices, get-display-media

We can request a media stream to a screen or windows via `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()`. However, this immediately prompts the user to decide which kind of capturing to use. I need to check if the browser/platform even support screen capturing.

Of course, it is possible to check for `'getDisplayMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices`, but this just tells us if the API is supported by the browser. In particular, on FF and Chrome on Android, the API is defined and I can call `getDisplayMedia()`, but it always immediately returns a `NotAllowedError` error (which is to be expected: [according to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_mediadevices_getdisplaymedia), the mobile browsers do not yet support `getDisplayMedia`.)

Next, I tried checking `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()`. However, my mobile FF returns the exact same object as my desktop FF. In particular, `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints().mediaSource` is `true` in both cases. Finally, the data returned by `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` does not help me either. I only get a device and group ID which I cannot interpret in any way (right?).

**Is it possible to detect whether or not screen capture via `getDisplayMedia` is supported beforehand?**

(*Note*: [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101264/detect-firefox-support-for-screen-sharing/46101620#46101620) seems fairly similar, but is about `getUserMedia` and is already quite old)

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @str Yes, I am. Also note that this question is not about "I can't use `getDisplayMedia` on mobile". That is fine for me. I just want to check *whether or not* it is supported.

Comment: Doesn't getDisplayMedia return a promise?

Comment: @aksappy Yes. Why? I don't see how that would help me. Either it resolves immediately to an error (on mobile) or the user get prompted by the browser (desktop, if supported).

Comment: Well, that was more of a conversation starter :-) Have you looked at MediaRecorder? It solves your use case with a isTypeSupported method.

Comment: @aksappy Ah ok, sorry, didn't understand that :D The `isTypeSupported` method can only check MIME types, right? So that wouldn't really help me detect whether or not `getDisplayMedia` is supported. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to feature-detect whether *getDisplayMedia* will work on those browsers.

All you can do today is [browser-sniff the UA string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device) to detect you're not on mobile, where support is lacking.¹

I've filed  an [issue on the spec](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-screen-share/issues/127) based on your question, to see if *getDisplayMedia* is better left `undefined` when unsupported.

---

<sub>1. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_mediadevices_getdisplaymedia) claims Opera Mobile has support, but this appears not so when I [test it](https://jan-ivar.github.io/dummy/gdm.html).</sub>

Comment: Please upvote this chromium bug report to get this fixed
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1038244#c2