# getDisplayMedia() not working correctly on Android device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, webrtc, get-display-media

I need co connect user display media(screen capture) to a webRTC application.

The following code is used to initiate screen capture:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true})
```

This prompts the user about the screen capture and creates a video stream that can be used once the permission is granted. However I was unable to get it to run on iOS or Android devices.

iPad i was testing this on was unable to find `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia - undefined`
(iOS 13.3)

Chrome (v79) on Android shows the following error when i try to call it:

> DOMException: Invalid state

according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia
the error can be generated if the code was not initiated by the user action, but it should not be an issue in my case since the code is being called like so:

```
startScreenSharing = event => {
 navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true})
}

<Button onClick={this.startScreenSharing} />
```

event variable holds a valid event but i still get an "Invalid State" error.

This must be something that i'm missing, since it is working fine on desktop Chrome & Safari.

**Edit**

I came across this: [Demo of getDisplayMedia and screen recording](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia/) and having the same error generated on this webpage. Can this be due to my hardware device settings?

Comment: `getDisplayMedia` is not implemented on android. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58879212/918910).

Comment: Please upvote this Chromium bug report to get this fixed
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1038244#c2

Answer (score 5):

getDisplayMedia() is not supported on android and iOS.

As per [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) it is not currently supported in iOS or Android, but is supported on Macos in Safari 13.

Comment: The link shows it is supported in MacOS, not on iOS.

Comment: When will it be supported on Android?

Comment: Any update on this topic ?

Comment: @JimJin I think we don't know but an alternative would be to use a desktop web browser like Firefox on a smartphone by dual booting a mobile operating system like postmarketOS.